# Iteration of a variable to create two tables

Tags: opentbs

I have a variable with several values, I would like to iterate over the variable and create two distinct tables, one at the beginning of the document and another at the end.

However, when I replicate the table iteration code, only one is created. Is it possible to create two tables from the same variable?

.docx file text:

```
Some document start....

[onshow;block=begin;when [var1.total!=0]

| Name                      | Barcode          |
| ------------------------- | ---------------- |
| [var1.name;block=tbs:row] | [var1.barcode]   |

[onshow;block=end]


Some document middle....


[onshow;block=begin;when [var1.total!=0]

| Name                      | Barcode          |
| ------------------------- | ---------------- |
| [var1.name;block=tbs:row] | [var1.barcode]   |

[onshow;block=end]

Some end of document....
```

I tried to separate the tables into different paragraphs, but without success.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to use the same variable on to separete tables.

I will add an example, let's say that in your code you have this array:

```
$data = array(
    array('name' => 'First Name', 'barcode' => '03430242',),
    array('name' => 'Second Names', 'barcode' =>  '213123',),
    array('name' => 'Third Name', 'barcode'  => '8797567654',)
    );

$TBS->Plugin(TBS_INSTALL, OPENTBS_PLUGIN);

$TBS->LoadTemplate('your_template');
```

and all the basic to make it work

Now, for sure you are using `MergeBlock`,something like:

```
$TBS->MergeBlock('a', $data);
```

and like that you can use it in the table:

| Name | Barcode |
| --- | --- |
| [a.name;block=tbs:row] | [a.barcode] |

oke, so what you need to do is add another `MergeBlock`

```
$TBS->MergeBlock('b', $data);
```

but now the first parameter of `MergeBlock` it will be **'b'** not **'a'** (it's like a new instance however it uses `$data` too, the same array **'a'** is using)

Final result:

```
$TBS->MergeBlock('a', $data);
$TBS->MergeBlock('b', $data);



Some document start....

[onshow;block=begin;when [var1.total!=0]
```

| Name | Barcode |
| --- | --- |
| [a.name;block=tbs:row] | [a.barcode] |

```
[onshow;block=end]


Some document middle....


[onshow;block=begin;when [var1.total!=0]
```

| Name | Barcode |
| --- | --- |
| [b.name;block=tbs:row] | [b.barcode] |

```
[onshow;block=end]

Some end of document....
```

If you have any question just ask!